# Can't get map to render on react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, list, render

im trying to render a list of objects, when i try map on console it returns the information correctly, i just need to render the object name in a list, but everytime i reload nothing renders on the screen, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";
import { FcInfo } from 'react-icons/fc'
import { AiFillEdit } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { FiDelete } from 'react-icons/fi'
import { Card, InputGroup, FormControl, Button, DropdownButton, Dropdown,Table} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../auth/login.css'

import solicitudeService from "../services/solicitude.service";
import edificeService from "../services/edifice.service";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function MySolicitudes(){
var data=[]
    solicitudeService.getAll().then(response =>{
        data=response.data
        data.map((val, key)=>{
             console.log("TEST:",val.nombresolicitud,key);
        });
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
    
    
   
    return(
        <div className="container">
       <h3>Lista Espacios</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {data && data.map((val,index) =>{
           
           
           return( <li key={index}>
                {val.nombresolicitud}
            </li>);
            
          })

          }
        </ul>
        </div>
    );
} export default MySolicitudes;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `data` isn't part of the component's state, so reassigning it won't trigger a re-render.

Also, your code will currently call `solicitudeService.getAll()` on every render, which you probably don't want.

Try using the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hooks:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    solicitudeService.getAll().then(response =>{
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
}, []);
```

This will call `solicitudeService.getAll()` once when the component is initially rendered, and then call `setData` which should trigger a re-render and give you the behavior you expect.

You can adjust the deps array for `useEffect` if you want to change when `solicitudeService.getAll()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not a state variable here and as such does not excecute a rerender of your view (your load of the data via the solicitudeService is not synchronos and as such the data is not there when the page renders).

Put the data in a `useState` hook and call the setter inside of youre solicitudeService.

Something like:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState()

solicitudeService.getAll().then(response =>{
        setData(response.data)
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
});
```